# How to pause for a few seconds between GUI updates?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am visualizing an incremental algorithm and at each step in the algorithm I want to update the GUI, pause for a couple of seconds, then continue on to the next step of the algorithm (and repeat).

What is the prefered method of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use a QTimer (either instantiate a QTimer object and call start() on it, or just call QTimer::singleShot()).  Update your GUI in the slot connected to the QTimer's timeout() signal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the QT function QThread:sleep()
See QT docs at: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qthread.html#sleep

Comment: Sleeping in the GUI thread is a bad idea because it freezes up the GUI and makes it unresponsive to the user, which makes for a bad user experience.